# Laravel validators: prevent submit 2 parameters together

Tags: php, laravel, validation, laravel-5, laravel-validation

How to prevent presents of 2 parameters that existed in `required_without_all` validator, ex:

```
    return [
        'user' => 'required_without_all:customer,public',
        'customer' => 'required_without_all:user,public',
        'public' => 'required_without_all:user,customer',

    ];
```

How to prevent user from submit 2 keys from above together, ex:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/app/groups-statistics?user=10&customer=10
```

These are allowed requests:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/app/groups-statistics?user=10
http://127.0.0.1:8000/app/groups-statistics?customer=10
http://127.0.0.1:8000/app/groups-statistics?public=true
```

Disallowed:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/app/groups-statistics?pubilc=true&customer=10
http://127.0.0.1:8000/app/groups-statistics?user=10&customer=10
http://127.0.0.1:8000/app/groups-statistics?public=10&customer=10
```

Comment: you need a custom `Rule`

Comment: Why don't you just take the very first parameter from the url, and do necessary validation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Validator extension to make your own validator:

In `AppServiceProvider`'s put this code: (or in any provider)

```
public function boot(){
  Validator::extend('present_only_one_from', function ($attribute, $value, $params, $validator) {
      // $params = [user,customer,public]

      $data = array_keys(array_filter($validator->getData())); // or you can write request()->all()
      // $data = [user,customer] or [user,customer,public] or [user] ...

      $intersect = array_intersect($data, $params); // returns matches of received and in validation rules


      // $intersect [user,customer] && [user,customer,public] => [user,customer] => invalid
      // $intersect [user] && [user,customer,public] => [user] => ($intersect[0] !== $attribute) => valid
      // $intersect [customer] && [user,customer,public] => [customer] => ($intersect[0] !== $attribute) => invalid
      if (count($intersect) != 1 && $intersect[0] !== $attribute) return false;

      return true;
  });
}
```

> The custom validator Closure receives four arguments: the name of the $attribute being validated, the $value of the attribute, an array of $parameters passed to the rule, and the Validator instance.

Then in any controller you can use this rules:

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->request->all(), [
    'user' => 'present_only_one_from:user,customer,public',
    'customer' => 'present_only_one_from:user,customer,public',
    'public' => 'present_only_one_from:user,customer,public',
]);
```

hope this helps you

Answer (score -2):

You can't use Laravel validators to handle the URL query string, you have to use a middleware instead.

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class ValidateQueryString
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if ($public = $request->query('public')) {
            if ($customer = $request->query('customer')) {
                //Here both exist, handle your logic error
            }
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```